# C# midnight timer invoked prematurely

Tags: c#, events, timer

My system needs to update its DB at midnight, every day.
The value is a daily usage counter.
In order to do so I've coded this class:

```
internal class MidnightTimer
{
    internal event EventHandler Elapsed = delegate { };
    private Timer timer;

    internal MidnightTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    }

    internal void Start()
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpanToMidnight = GetNextMidnight().Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        timer.Interval = timeSpanToMidnight.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Elapsed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        timer.Stop();
        Start();
    }

    private static DateTime GetNextMidnight()
    {
        const string datePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
        const string dateFormat = "{0:00}/{1:00}/{2:0000} {3:00}:{4:00}:{5:00}";
        DateTime nextMidnight;

        string dateString = string.Format(dateFormat, DateTime.Now.Day + 1, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year, 0, 0, 0);
        bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, datePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out nextMidnight);

        if (!valid)
        {
            dateString = string.Format(dateFormat, 1, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, DateTime.Now.Year, 0, 0, 0);
            valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, datePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out nextMidnight);
        }

        if (!valid)
        {
            dateString = string.Format(dateFormat, 1, 1, DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, datePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out nextMidnight);
        }

        return nextMidnight;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is not accurate.
The event is sometimes invoked a few milliseconds before midnight, and because I'm resetting the value after it is sent to the DB in  the first event, it is resetting the value in the DB after the second event.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you formatting a string and then parsing it in order to get the next midnight? And what do you expect it to do on the last day of the month? I think you just want `DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`. That probably won't help with the accuracy of the timer, but it'll avoid your complicated code.

Comment: I've tried your method of calculating the next day and had some exceptions when I'm at the last day of a month or/and a leap year. When doing a validation test, with the `DateTime.TryParseExact` function, I've manage to avoid those exceptions.

Comment: No, you *won't* have any exceptions if you use `DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`. What exception could you get? It really is a *much* better approach.

Comment: Timers tick with a resolution that's 16 msec at best.  Being off by a few milliseconds is meaningless.  You cannot ever improve that, your code is not running on a real-time operating system that can provide a hard guarantee like that.  And of course you are also measuring the start-up time of your program, that's completely unpredictable as well.  A dependency on the exact day that the code runs is trivially avoided by running it 5 minutes after midnight.

Comment: To avoid getting two inputs in the DB, I'm currently running the timer at 00:00:05. I'm looking for a solution on how to update the DB at exactly 00:00:00. I was thinking of using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net) but its seems like a much bigger hammer for such a small nail.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've taken your advice and I'm calculating the new midnight like this `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)`, thanks.

Comment: @toy4fun: DateTime.Now.Date is equivalent to DateTime.Today, just more verbose.

Comment: Anyone cares to give his opinion of using Quartz? Will it behave the same? Is it overkill for such a task? Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the new code for the MidnightTimer class:

```
internal class MidnightTimer
{
    internal event EventHandler Elapsed = delegate { };
    private Timer timer;
    private DateTime previousRun;

    internal MidnightTimer()
    {
        SystemEvents.TimeChanged += SystemEvents_TimeChanged;

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    }

    internal void Start()
    {
        previousRun = DateTime.Today;

        TimeSpan timeSpanToMidnight = GetNextMidnight().Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        timer.Interval = timeSpanToMidnight.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (previousRun != DateTime.Today)
            Elapsed(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        timer.Stop();
        Start();
    }

    private void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        Start();
    }

    private static DateTime GetNextMidnight()
    {
        return DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

I've improved the `GetNextMidnight` function, by @JonSkeet advice.
I've set the `AutoReset` property to False.
I've added a compare check between the timer's previous run date the current date.
I've also register to the `SystemEvents.TimeChanged` event in order to recalculate the timer next run.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assume a timer event to be raised with millisecond-precision. The precision depends on a lot of factors, including the load of the system at the time when it needs to fire, the process priority etc. Here, also the clock skew or any clock adjustments come into play, because you're computing an event that will happen a whole day later.

Since I'm assuming that for the event itself, it doesn't really matter that it isn't precise, I'd just save the time of the last event in a variable and use that for computing the next. If you really must make sure you get only one event every night, you'd even have to save the time of the last event in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you build in a margin for error and then, when your Timer elapses, if you are within that period before midnight, reset the Timer.  You can keep doing that until the the event is raised after midnight.

Comment: I would suspect that the act itself of checking the margin will solve the problem. The margin will be about a few milliseconds which the timer itself varies within. I'm hoping I made it clear...

Comment: Yeah, it's likely that only one correction would ever be needed but the code should be written to allow for repeated corrections to be sure.